# Combine these 2 queries into 1. They work individually

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am not a sql expert and I cannot seem to get this to work. This is for a moodle database query.

cmi.core.total_time & cmi.core.lesson_status are both under the element column in the prefix_scorm_scoes_track table. I only need entries where cmi.core.lesson_status value (next column) = completed, but I also need the value of cmi.core.total_time.

```
SELECT u.firstname FIRST,u.lastname LAST,c.fullname Course, st.attempt Attempt,st.value STATUS,FROM_UNIXTIME(st.timemodified,"%m-%d-%Y") DATE 
FROM prefix_scorm_scoes_track AS st 
JOIN prefix_user AS u ON st.userid=u.id
JOIN prefix_scorm AS sc ON sc.id=st.scormid
JOIN prefix_course AS c ON c.id=sc.course
WHERE st.value='completed' 
ORDER BY c.fullname, u.lastname,u.firstname, st.attempt




SELECT u.firstname FIRST,u.lastname LAST,ui.data Role,c.fullname Course, st.attempt Attempt,st.value "Completion Time",FROM_UNIXTIME(st.timemodified,"%m/%d/%y %h:%i") DATE
FROM prefix_scorm_scoes_track AS st 
JOIN prefix_user AS u ON st.userid=u.id
JOIN prefix_user_info_data AS ui ON ui.userid=u.id AND fieldid = 1
JOIN prefix_scorm AS sc ON sc.id=st.scormid
JOIN prefix_course AS c ON c.id=sc.course
WHERE st.element='cmi.core.total_time' 
ORDER BY c.fullname, u.lastname,u.firstname, st.attempt
```

Comment: Is it MariaDB or MySQL? What version?

Comment: LEFT JOIN prefix_user_info_data . At the end. OR the conditions. etc.

Comment: you can use union all for combine result.

Comment: it is a MariaDB

Comment: Please elaborate, I am not familiar with SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.firstname FIRST,u.lastname LAST,ui.data Role,c.fullname Course, st.attempt Attempt,st.value "Completion Time",FROM_UNIXTIME(st.timemodified,"%m/%d/%y %h:%i") DATE
FROM prefix_scorm_scoes_track AS st 
JOIN prefix_user AS u ON st.userid=u.id
JOIN prefix_user_info_data AS ui ON ui.userid=u.id AND fieldid = 1
JOIN prefix_scorm AS sc ON sc.id=st.scormid
JOIN prefix_course AS c ON c.id=sc.course
WHERE st.element='cmi.core.total_time'  or st.value='completed'
ORDER BY c.fullname, u.lastname,u.firstname, st.attempt
```

Comment: please try this as you need to get the records where element='cmi.core.total_time' or st.value='completed'

Comment: This works, However, it creates 2 rows with the or part.
The 2 columns causing the issue are st.element and st.value.
st element has 4 different data points. 2 of which are cmi.core.total_time and cmi.core.lesson_status and on the st.value column I only want to show userids that have completed in value table and then pull the st.value in the row of cmi.core.total_time.  I wish I knew better how to explain this.